# Cloudformation error: Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/}: [UserData]]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Been trying to create a cloud formation template. I have been trying to use the UserData section and have reduced the template to the bones to identify what the problem is:

I am getting the error: Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/}: [UserData]]

This is my now totally barebones template. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. Can someone help please?

```
    {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "319ac38d-a9ea-4855-9a9a-4dc91f6ef092": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": -310,
                    "y": 30
                },
                "z": 1,
                "embeds": []
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "Cloud9Template": {
            "Type": "AWS::Cloud9::EnvironmentEC2",
            "Properties": {
                "UserData":{
                    "Fn::Base64" : {
                        "Fn::Join" : [ ",", [
                            "test",
                            "Hello World" ] ]
                    }
                },
                "AutomaticStopTimeMinutes": "45",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "Name": {
                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "319ac38d-a9ea-4855-9a9a-4dc91f6ef092"
                },
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                    "sources" : {
                      "/home/ec2-user/environment/src" : <linktotarball>"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [AWS::Cloud9::EnvironmentEC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloud9-environmentec2.html) **does not support** `UserData` as shown in its [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloud9-environmentec2.html).

In other words, you can't use UserData in the definition of `EnvironmentEC2` resource.

Comment: Thank you---unfortunate. Is there any other way to do trigger the AWS::CloudFormation::Init"  in the AWS::Cloud9::EnvironmentEC2?

Comment: @KelakeMadiradu Sadly, I'm not aware of such a method.

Comment: Thank you anyhow. I will figure someway out. May need load more steps....

Comment: Sure there is. There is a UserData property under the LaunchTemplateData property.